# Sixteen Two's to get Two Thousand and Twenty-Two

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Get the number 2022 by only using the number 2 a maximum of 16 times. **There is a solution.**

Allowed:

- $+$
- $-$
- $*$
- "$()$"
- "$\frac x y$"
- $x^y$ Note: When you use $2^2$, it counts as using two 2s, not one 2!
- $\sqrt x$

**Follow-Up:** Can you do the same with number 3? ***But*** without square-roots, without raising to the power, and without using parenthesis?

Comment: Why does the title say 2023, when the question asks for 2022?

Comment: I edited the question (typo), but forgot to change the title

Comment: @fljx Thanks, for pointing it out!

Comment: I meant one 2, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution (powers down to top):

> $\left({\left({2^2}\right)^2}\right)^2 \times 2\times2\times2 - ({2^2})^2\times2 +2+2+2 \times \frac22 = 2022$

Question 2:

> Because this one only allows the four main operations, PEMDAS/BODMAS requires that 2022 must be the sum/difference of multiple powers of three. An economical solution would be $3^7 - 3^4 - 3^4 - 3 = 3\times3\times3\times3\times3\times3\times3 - 3\times3\times3\times3 - 3\times3\times3\times3 - 3 = 2022$  
>  Proof that this is the only solution: 
>  $(2022)_3 = 2202220$ (not doable by adding the first 2s)
>  $(3^7-2022)_3 = 20010$ (or -$2220$, but it's not doable either, so just stick to $20010$ as in using 9 more threes)

Comment: Not my wanted solution, but correct nontheless!

Comment: View my Solution, and view follow up question!

Comment: You have the exact same solution, I posted 30 minutes ago, *for the follow-up question*! But it is possibly the only solution :P

Comment: The first solution uses division, which is not in the list of allowed operations. You can replace the x2/2 with +2-2

Comment: $x/y$ is allowed.

Comment: @Nautilus After fljx' warnings.

Answer (score 6):

Solution using only 3 operations and brackets because simple is nice:

> $(2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2) ^ 2 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2) \times 2 + (2 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2)) + 2 = 2022$

How!?!

> $(2\times2\times2+2) = 10 \implies (2\times2\times2+2)^2 = 100 \implies \left[(2\times2\times2+2)\times(2\times2\times2+2)^2\right] = 1000 \implies \left[(2\times2\times2+2)\times(2\times2\times2+2)^2\right]\times2 = 2000\text{ }\&\text{ }[(2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2) \times 2 + (2 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2))]=20 \therefore [(2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2) ^ 2 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2) \times 2 + (2 \times (2 \times 2 \times 2 + 2)) + 2] = 2022$

---

#### Totally unrelated side note

I notice people using the letter <kbd>x</kbd> to represent multiplication, but you can actually use `\times` within MathJax, which results in $\times$.

Comment: oh wow thanks i didnt know that I learned something today

Answer (score 4):

Because roots are cool:

> $ [ 2 \sqrt(\sqrt(2)) \times (\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(2))) ] ^{2\times2\times2} -[2\times2-\sqrt(2)]^2 - [2 +2\sqrt(2)]^2 +2^2 = 2022$

Answer (score -1):

My answer would have been:

> $\left(\left(2^2\right)^2\right)^2 \times \left(2^2 \times 2 \right) - (2^2)^2 - 2^2 \times 2 - 2 = 2022$

For the follow-up:

> $3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 - 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 - 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 - 3 = 2022$

Comment: Your first answer uses division, which is not in the list of allowed operations

Comment: It is in the list

Comment: It's there now. It wasn't when I made that comment.

Comment: Agree with @fljx, if you're trying to stretch the rules, please don't. If it was an honest mistake though, that's fine.

Comment: It was an honest mistake

Comment: I had both solutions in mind before I posted the question. But then I had to look into how to format it with the "$" so and so forth, that I forgot some stuff.

Comment: @newQOpenWid, fljx, I changed it, so that it doesn't use fractions, just for you